# Gulpfiles how to make build on command instead of automatically?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Good afternoon, there is an assembly project on `gulp`. After each change, the finished project is assembled.

It is a little uncomfortable to control the versions.

How to make the project build only on command `gulp-build`? At the moment it is implemented automatically, but you need to build it by command.

**gulpfiles**

```js
let project_folder = require("path").basename(__dirname);
let source_folder = "src";

let fs = require('fs');

let path = {
  build: {
    html: project_folder + "/",
    css: project_folder + "/css/",
    js: project_folder + "/js/",
    img: project_folder + "/images/",
    fonts: project_folder + "/fonts/",
  },
  src: {
    html: [source_folder + "/*.html", "!" + source_folder + "/_*.html"],
    css: source_folder + "/scss/style.scss",
    js: source_folder + "/js/script.js",
    img: source_folder + "/images/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}",
    fonts: source_folder + "/fonts/*.ttf",
  },
  watch: {
    html: source_folder + "/**/*.html",
    css: source_folder + "/scss/**/*.scss",
    js: source_folder + "/js/**/*.js",
    img: source_folder + "/images/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}"
  },
  clean: "./" + project_folder + "/"
}

let {
  src,
  dest
} = require('gulp'),
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  browsersync = require("browser-sync").create(),
  fileinclude = require("gulp-file-include"),
  del = require("del"),
  scss = require("gulp-sass"),
  autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
  group_media = require("gulp-group-css-media-queries"),
  clean_css = require("gulp-clean-css"),
  rename = require("gulp-rename"),
  uglify = require("gulp-uglify-es").default,
  imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin"),
  // webp = require('gulp-webp'),
  // webphtml = require('gulp-webp-html'),
  // webpcss = require("gulp-webpcss"),
  svgSprite = require('gulp-svg-sprite'),
  ttf2woff = require('gulp-ttf2woff'),
  ttf2woff2 = require('gulp-ttf2woff2'),
  fonter = require('gulp-fonter');

function browserSync(params) {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./" + project_folder + "/"
    },
    port: 3000,
    notify: false
  })
}

function html() {
  return src(path.src.html)
    .pipe(fileinclude())
    // .pipe(webphtml())
    .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function css() {
  return src(path.src.css)
    .pipe(
      scss({
        outputStyle: "expanded"
      })
    )
    .pipe(
      group_media()
    )
    .pipe(
      autoprefixer({
        overrideBrowserslist: ["last 5 versions"],
        cascade: true
      })
    )
    // .pipe(webpcss())
    .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(clean_css())
    .pipe(
      rename({
        extname: ".min.css"
      })
    )
    .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function js() {
  return src(path.src.js)
    .pipe(fileinclude())
    .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
    .pipe(
      uglify()
    )
    .pipe(
      rename({
        extname: ".min.js"
      })
    )
    .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function images() {
  return src(path.src.img)
    // .pipe(
    //     webp({
    //         quality: 70
    //     })
    // )
    .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
    .pipe(src(path.src.img))
    .pipe(
      imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        svgoPlugins: [{
          removeViewBox: false
        }],
        interlaced: true,
        optimizationLevel: 3 // 0 to 7
      })
    )
    .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function fonts() {
  src(path.src.fonts)
    .pipe(ttf2woff())
    .pipe(dest(path.build.fonts));
  return src(path.src.fonts)
    .pipe(ttf2woff2())
    .pipe(dest(path.build.fonts));
};

gulp.task('otf2ttf', function() {
  return src([source_folder + '/fonts/*.otf'])
    .pipe(fonter({
      formats: ['ttf']
    }))
    .pipe(dest(source_folder + '/fonts/'));
})

gulp.task('svgSprite', function() {
  return gulp.src([source_folder + '/iconsprite/*.svg'])
    .pipe(svgSprite({
      mode: {
        stack: {
          sprite: "../icons/icons.svg", //sprite file name
          example: true
        }
      },
    }))
    .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
})

function fontsStyle(params) {
  let file_content = fs.readFileSync(source_folder + '/scss/fonts.scss');
  if (file_content == '') {
    fs.writeFile(source_folder + '/scss/fonts.scss', '', cb);
    return fs.readdir(path.build.fonts, function(err, items) {
      if (items) {
        let c_fontname;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          let fontname = items[i].split('.');
          fontname = fontname[0];
          if (c_fontname != fontname) {
            fs.appendFile(source_folder + '/scss/fonts.scss', '@include font("' + fontname + '", "' + fontname + '", "400", "normal");\r\n', cb);
          }
          c_fontname = fontname;
        }
      }
    })
  }
}

function cb() {

}

function watchFiles(params) {
  gulp.watch([path.watch.html], html);
  gulp.watch([path.watch.css], css);
  gulp.watch([path.watch.js], js);
  gulp.watch([path.watch.img], images);
}

function clean(params) {
  return del(path.clean);
}

let build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(js, css, html, images, fonts), fontsStyle);
let watch = gulp.parallel(build, watchFiles, browserSync);

exports.fontsStyle = fontsStyle;
exports.fonts = fonts;
exports.images = images;
exports.js = js;
exports.css = css;
exports.html = html;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "del": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
    "gulp-file-include": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp-fonter": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-group-css-media-queries": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-svg-sprite": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-ttf2woff": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-ttf2woff2": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify-es": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-webp": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-webp-html": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-webpcss": "^1.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```